# Почему некоторые значения min и max повторяются?

Tags: javascript

У меня возник один вопрос по поводу моего задания. Нужно сделать так, что бы программа сама отгадывала число введенное пользователем. Вот мое решение, но есть одна проблема: программа отгадывает то число, но иногда повторяет значения min или max. Что то типо "Ваше число больше или эквивалентно 13?" - я к примеру отвечаю да(то есть число не эквивалентно, а больше :), и оно может снова спросить "Ваше число больше или эквивалентно 13?", а после этого продолжает нормально работать. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

```
function guess_programm() {
var number; 
var min = 0;
var max = 30;
var random_number = Math.floor(min + (max-min+1)*Math.random());
number = prompt('Hi, let\'s play the game! Enter your number(from 0 to 30) and I will try to guess it :)', 'I close my eyes, so you can write -o-');

while (max != min || min != max) 
{

    var answer = prompt('OK, your number bigger then or it is equally to - ' + random_number, 'equally/yes/no');
    if (answer == 'equally')
    {
        alert('Yeeh, I wiin ^^');
        break;
    }
    else if (answer == 'yes')  
    {   
        min = random_number;
    }

    else if (answer == 'no')
    {   
        max = random_number;
    }
    random_number = Math.floor(min + (max-min+1)*Math.random());

}


alert('Your number is - ' + number); }
```

Comment: `max != min || min != max` это JS особенность что == нетранзитивно и надо так писать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта конструкция

```
Math.floor(min + (max-min+1)*Math.random())
```

вам выдаёт случайное число от минимума до максимума - в том числе это может оказаться сам минимум или максимум. А один из них является как раз тем числом, которое было на прошлом этапе.

Вообще, в такого рода задачах лучше использовать не случайное число из интервала, а его середину.

Comment: `min = random_number;` тут наверно +1 надо ещё.

Comment: @pavel а если `random_number` окажется максимумом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну нам же сказали что задуманное _больше_ его, раз мы в эту ветку зашли. Иначе можно на паре [1,2] к примеру брать середину (1) и вечный цикл.